# Mandrill merge variables in href disabling click measure

Tags: mandrill

I've set up an email template with handlebar variables.
Everything works except the fact **the href that contains a merge variable is not changed into a mandrillapp.com tracking url**, thus not counting in the click stats.

Meaning this :

```
<a href="http://example.com/{{path}}">Yeah</a>
```

Ends up looking like this in the email

```
<a href="http://example.com/areyouready.htm">Yeah</a>
```

While I was expecting

```
<a href="http://mandrillapp.com/track/click/xxx">Yeah</a>
```

It used to work, and I wonder if it wasn't when I was using standard mailChimp-style variables, that is * |THING| * instead of {{thing}}.

I need my click stats.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I answer myself.

The fact is this is probably not related to merge variables, but rather url length. My url is in fact 300 chars longs - which my fake example didn't show - and Mandrill drops tracking after 255 chars.

I knew I'd get trouble having such a long url, but I didn't expect it to fail tracking.